# How to run two node versions on linux system?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, nvm

How to run two different node versions parallel on same system? I've tried looking for solution on web, but all solutions are about switching node versions.

Comment: This link contains a detailed steps...please look into it, might be helpful..
https://www.tecmint.com/nvm-install-multiple-nodejs-versions-in-linux/

Answer (score -1):

```
nvm run {version} {command}
```

e.g.

```
nvm run 9 abc.js
```

This will run with Node.js v9

More info on: https://medium.com/@luongnhutoan/how-to-run-multiple-versions-of-nodejs-with-nvm-3c40aa25c359